# Spelling check in Emacs 25.2 on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: auctex, spell-checking

I am new to Emacs and I have a hard time to have spelling check when I use Emacs+AUCTex.

Here is a list of what I have done so far:

1. I read on a post saying that I should not install Flyspell. So I did not.
2. I followed some instructions on `Homebrew`. I *think* I have installed `ispell` successfully.
3. When I tried to install `aspell`, it says `Error: No available formula with the name "aspell-en"`.

Now when I use `M-x ispell`, it says `Searching for program: No such file or directory, ispell`.

I saw different solutions online and tried some, but none of them worked. And since I am new to Emacs, I also do not want to mess up my `.emacs` file too much. So I come here for some help.

Comment: Flyspell minor mode comes built-in with emacs. No need to install it.

Comment: What command you used to try to install aspell? 'brew install aspell' should work. If it does not, update your brew database and try again.

Comment: You have not installed ispell succesfully. There should be an executable with that name. Unix command 'which ispell' should show where it is.

Comment: Usually this happens if your Emacs does not read the $PATH properly. Search for what to do in your system to make sure your $PATH is available to Emacs.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you need to get `aspell` installed correctly.  As mentioned in the comments "`brew install aspell`" should be all you need.  If that doesn't work then you have a problem with `brew`.  By default this will install the "`aspell`" executable (note that it's not called "`ispell`") into `/usr/local/bin`.  You need to tell Emacs to use "`aspell`" instead of "`ispell`" which you can do by adding `(setq ispell-program-name "/usr/local/bin/aspell")` to your Emacs init file.  Running `M-x ispell` should then run your aspell programme.

Comment: From my experience Emacs has a fallback list, and it should be able to find `aspell` without any configuration. Setting the path to it makes sense if you are trying to install `aspell` on the fly after you figured out you don't have it and you don't want to restart Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

First, to install on brew just use `brew install aspell`, without the `-en` that is a dictionary file which you can install later (but the brew aspell comes with English).  Then go to Terminal and type `which aspell` it should tell you where `aspell` is installed. If it gives you a directory you can actually type `aspell check textfile.txt` (insert a text file name in that directory) to check its operation.  After that Emacs should figure itself out.  If not then you need to do a quick check for setup file settings again.

Answer (score -1):

flyspell is an independent minor mode which use a few APIs from ispell. So you **are actually using flyspell instead of ispell** to do the spelling check.

1. flyspell is built in package of Emacs. You don't need install it manually
2. "I think I have installed ispell successfully" doesn't make sense. You need install aspell and its dictionaries. Then you need tweak a few variables from ispell to actually use flyspell (as I mentioned, flyspell re-use a few APIs from ispell)
3. See https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/2419 , make sure you have the right version of aspell installed from homebrew (try `which aspell` in shell)

After installing aspell and its dictionaries successfully, you need setup flyspell,

```
 (setq ispell-program-name "aspell")
 ;; Please note ispell-extra-args contains ACTUAL parameters passed to aspell
 (setq ispell-extra-args '("--sug-mode=ultra" "--lang=en_US")
```

Usage is simple, either `M-x flyspell-buffer` to manually check the buffer for once or `M-x flyspell-mode` to turn on on-the-fly spell checking.

See http://blog.binchen.org/posts/what-s-the-best-spell-check-set-up-in-emacs.html for details.